# After install magento extension, but the extension is not working like not installed

Tags: magento

I'm using magento 1.6.2.0.
When I install some extension in Magento connect, the black message box said 
"Checking dependencies of packages
Installing package community/TBT_Enhancedgrid 1.3.2.1
Package community/TBT_Enhancedgrid 1.3.2.1 installed successfully
Package installed: 
 community TBT_Enhancedgrid 1.3.2.1"

But I feel the extension is not installed.

First when I install magento, and then enter Magento connection menu, the red error message occurred like this.

"Warning: Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions."

So I changed folder permission, then the error message was gone.

And after that any extension installed fine, but the extension is not showing up at System -> Configuration - > Advanced -> Disable Modules Output.

I've installed same extension several times other sites. That was works fine.

But this time is very weird.

somebody know the reason??

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there's several poorly coded extensions in Magento Connect and you should always test them before promoting any changes to a live site.

That being said, there could be a couple things that are issues. First, check that the module actually installed in the */app/code/community* folder. Also check that there exists something similar to TBT_Enhancedgrid.xml in the */app/etc/modules* folder - this is the file that actually enables your module. Does it contain code similar to this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Example_Module>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <active>true</active>
    </Example_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

If it doesn't, then it will not enable properly. Secondly, try flushing the entire cache storage via *System > Cache Management > Flush Cache Storage*. Third, try logging out of the administrative panel and logging back in.

It's also important to check the user reviews on Magento Connect as they may reveal critical details on how it functions and if it breaks any functionality within Magento itself.

Comment: Instead of `Flush Cache Storage`, just `Flush Magento Cache` should do the trick.

Comment: @seanbreeden nope. Sometimes it doesn't go far enough and you have to go 100%.